# Suppress creation of slot accessors for cl-defstruct :include slots?

Tags: cl-lib

Is it possible to suppress creation of slot accessors for slots included via `:include`?  For example, in the following:

```
(cl-defstruct person name (age 0) sex)
(cl-defstruct (astronaut (:include person (age 45)))
  helmet-size
  (favorite-beverage 'tang))
```

**How can I prevent the accessor `astronaut-name`,`astronaut-age`, and `astronaut-sex` from being created?**

It's possible to do the following after definition, so it is mostly a curiosity about the capabilities of `cl-lib`.

```
(setf (symbol-function 'astronaut-name) nil)
(setf (symbol-function 'astronaut-name--cmacro) nil)
...
```

Comment: Interesting question, but since I believe `cl` package tried to follow Common Lisp as close as possible, and you seem to have red Hyperspec (judging by the names you chose for the structs), I wouldn't expect there to be a way to do it.

Comment: Also, looking at implementation, it seems like there's no easy way to do that. It was definitely not planned for.

Comment: @wvxvw If you want to create an answer, I'll mark it accepted.  I'll eventually devise a macro for this and include it here.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know the rationale behind this decision. This is what I was thinking: a way to embed a struct is to put its fields in front of the fields of embedding struct, thus functions accessing the embedded one would still work on the embedding. Obviously, this prevents embedding multiple structs. Another way to deal with this is to have a special field in the struct which keeps offsets per embedded struct, which allows more flexibility. I belive `cl` library does the later (comments in the code suggest multiple inclusion is possible).

Comment: However, in the second case, it would be necessary to generate some code to enable polymorphism: there should be an entry in a table of the special slot of the struct instructing accessors as to the offsets they need to use to access the fields. So you cannot not generate that part. It is also possible that accessors of the embedded struct use accessors of embedding struct to get to the value of the field, thus I'd be careful about deleting those: the implementation may change in such a way that it will make those accessors mandatory.

Comment: @wvxvw (1) I'm fairly certain that cl-defstruct only enables single inheritance. (2) I would find it surprising if the the embedded struct ever relied on the public accessor of the embedding struct, it would be unnecessarily fragile implementation IMO- especially with cowboys out there thinking about keeping their symbol table clean :-P

Comment: There's a comment inside this macro which suggests that it is in principle possible to support multiple inheritance. Not sure if they will ever act on it.